# |x| is continuous at R

Tags: calculus, limits

So I have this limit definition: A function $f:A→R$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if for any $ϵ>0$, there is a $δ>0$ so that $|x − x_0| < δ ⇒ |f(x) − f(x_0)| < ϵ$. So using this definition only I have to prove that $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous at $R$.

Comment: Hint: Triangle inequality.

Comment: Simply rewrite the definitions with $f(x)=\left| x\right|$

Comment: @NiklasHebestreit Are you sure I can apply this to the above definition?

Comment: @George Sure, just have a look at user389056's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|x-x_0| < \epsilon = \delta$. Then since $||x| - |x_0|| \leq |x-x_0| < \epsilon$, you're done.